# Element won't center inside Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm currently using the React Bootstrap Modal. I'm trying to center an element within a modal with flexbox, but having a lot of trouble doing just that. Below is my code, and how it currently looks.

[image]
[image]

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as welcome from '../../styles/welcome'

class Welcome extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
    showModal: true
 }
this.close=this.close.bind(this)
this.open=this.open.bind(this)
}

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  debugger
  if(nextProps.modal_content !== this.props.modal_content){
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
 }
}

close(){
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
}

open() {
  this.setState({ showModal: true });
}

 render() {

return (
  <div>
    <Modal style={welcome.welcomeBody} show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>

        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
           <div style={{backgroundColor: 'black', border: '1px solid black', borderRadius: '100%', width: '50px', height: '50px'}}></div>
       </div>


    </Modal>
  </div>
);
}
 }
```

export default Welcome

Comment: You can try centring your element using flex with CSS

Comment: can you paste the rendered HTML ? along with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `flex` in the `image` to align it `center`...which is wrong...

`Flex` always be applied to the `parent` container so that its children items use the flex features.

Wrap your `image` in a `div` and then apply `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to that div so that image will be aligned centered.

```
<div style={{display: 'flex',justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <img src="pic.png"></img>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

**Updated Code**

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
  <div style="background-color:black;border:1px solid;height:50px;width:50px;border-radius:50%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @acampbe222 it should work...make sure your rendered html should look like the above example...Try to apply `width:100%` to that div

Comment: Just posted a pic of how it looks

Comment: @acampbe222 could you share the screenshot of the rendered html in console

Comment: Edited the question with new pic @Bhuwan

Comment: @acampbe222 why is there width and height values in your `.modal` class div...?

Comment: Wow. It was my fault. I tried to style the modal to a certain size, but didn't realize until you pointed out that the width was throwing off the flex centering. Thx!